# Using groovy.sql.Sql.executeInsert() within a Java program

Tags: java, oracle, groovy

**EDIT** Changing the question due to new information

I'm using the Groovy SQL library in a Java program and having trouble when inserting rows in an Oracle database with the executeInsert() function.

This is a fragment of my Java program:

```
    DataSet myds = registry.lookupByNameAndType("myDataSet", DataSet.class);

// Use a stored function to add a row to the database and provide a keyword reference
    int[] updateCounts = myds.withBatch(100,  new Closure<Object>(this) {
        public Object doCall(DataSet ds) {
            Integer dupCount = 0;
            String sqlString = 
                "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE " +
                "(A_NUMBER_COLUMN) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "(':input_number')"; // one of the record Map elements
            List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
            List<String> keyColumnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            keyColumnNames.add("MY_ID_COLUMN");

            for (Map<String, Object>record : incoming) {
                try {
                    List<GroovyRowResult> keys = ds.executeInsert(record, sqlString, keyColumnNames);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dupCount++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return dupCount;
        };
    });
```

But, when the program executes, I get a SQL error that says:

> Failed to execute: INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A_NUMBER_COLUMN) VALUES (':input_number') because: Invalid column index

I've even tried replacing the named parameter ":input_number" with a question mark and with a constant number and got the same invalid column index error for each. It looks like the parameter substitution in the Groovy function is completely broken when used within a Java program.

Can anyone tell me how this is supposed to work? (And, no. I don't have the option of going to a straight Groovy program.)

Using groovy-all-2.4.11.jar and jdk.1.8.0_131

Thanks!

Comment: did you read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00900_invalid_sql_statement.htm

Comment: Thanks YCF_L. I had not seen that and it did provide some clues. I wrapped all of the ? parameter substitution marks in double quotes and now I'm not getting the "invalid SQL statement" error. Instead, I'm getting "invalid column index". So, now I need to see if there is a problem with the stored function itself.

Comment: I've changed the question because I discovered that the same problem occurs even without the added complication of the stored function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking at this for a while, I submitted a question to the Groovy User mailing list. Turns out that I uncovered a bug in Groovy. [JIRA issue submitted](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8174;cid=1493748540146-117)

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling a function that returns something you have to supply a bind and specify the type such as:

```
DataSet myds = registry.lookupByNameAndType("myDataSet", DataSet.class);

// Use a stored function to add a row to the database and provide a keyword reference
int[] updateCounts = myds.withBatch(100,  new Closure<Object>(this) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Object doCall(DataSet ds) {
        Integer dupCount = 0;

        String sqlString = "{? = call aStoredFunction ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )}";
        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (Map<String, Object>record : incoming) {
            params.clear();
            params.add(Sql.NUMERIC)
            params.add(record.get("param1"));
            params.add(record.get("param2"));
            params.add(record.get("param3"));
            params.add(record.get("param4"));
            params.add(record.get("param5"));
            params.add(record.get("param6"));
            params.add(record.get("param7"));
            params.add(record.get("param8"));
            params.add(record.get("param9"));

            try {
                sql.call( sqlString, params ) { result -> dupCount = result }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dupCount;
    };
});
```

Comment: Your additions look very groovy-like. I don't think they will work in a *.java file. I'd actually edited out the part of my code where dupCount was being set. I'll put it back in for clarity.